# Which of the following pairs of sets are homeomorphic of the following?

Tags: general-topology

Which of the following pairs of sets are homeomorphic?

> a. The set $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z$ with their usual topologies inherited from $\mathbb R.$
>
> b.The sets $(0,1)$ and (0,$\infty$) with their usual topologies inherited from $\mathbb R.$
>
> c. The sets $S^1=${$z\in\mathbb C: z=e^{i\theta},0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$} and$A$={$z\in\mathbb C:z=re^{i\theta},1\leq r\leq2,0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$} with their usual topologies inherited from $\mathbb C$ i.e. $\mathbb R^{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (a)is not homemophic because you can see the open and closed property in $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z$. $\mathbb Z$ has a discrete topological structure in $\mathbb R$, however, $\mathbb Q$ is not.
>
> (b)is homemorphic because we can construct a continuous map: $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$.
>
> (c)is not homeomorphic, because $\mathbb S^1$ is one dimensional manifold without boundary and $A$ is two dimensional manifold with boundary.